# FInding a folder in a specific location but not knowing the full folder name

Tags: batch-file, character, directory, rename

So im still struggling a bit to get this to work. Basically I have a folder with the first **seven** charaacters always known but the numbering included in the foldername is different each time (i.e time stamp is added to the end of the file name) Example the name of the folder might be **Project12345** and this is stored in the folder structure C:\Test\Test2. I always know that the name starts with **Project** so I was wondering how I could search for the folder in this location based on the first **seven** characters and then rename it to just **Project**?

Apologies for being so long winded!

Thanks 
John

Answer (score 0):

Use [rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx) for files

`rename Project* Project`

and use `move` for directories

`move Project* Project`

`rename` works on folders, but only if you don't use a wildcard.

Comment: Hi, its showing as incorrect syntax and will only work if i give the full folder name i.e Project12345....Any ideas?

Comment: Post full traceback and what you're trying to execute

Comment: Apologies, I just spotted your last reply. Move worked 100%. Thanks very much for your help. Regards.

Comment: Glad it helped, be sure to mark the answer as the solution, so others with this problem can find it!